# Form Objects: Use Reform Gem with User / Pet Example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, reform

Nick Sutterer's [Reform gem](https://github.com/apotonick/reform) appears to be awesome but for some reason i cannot grok how to apply it to my proof-of-concept Rails app.  I have read the docs and a number of blog posts but still do not fully understand how it would work.

Given the following criteria, what would the code for models, form object class, view and controller look like?

- The app has `User` and `Pet` models
- The signup form accepts a `User.email` and his `Pet.name`
- Users cannot signup without a valid email address
- When a user signs up the `User`'s account is created and a `pet` row is created and automatically associated to the user

Sample models:

A user

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end
```

His pet

```
# app/models/pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Reform is good. The author (Nick) has an entire book that includes lots of info about Reform. My suggestion is to buy the book. Or, if you're new to Rails, wait to try Reform and instead use SimpleForm.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson thanks for the suggestion. I actually considered buying the book but it's not even 50% done yet and this gem has been out since April 2013 :/

Comment: In the 3rd chapter I discuss Reform's basics. The 5th chapter which is coming early January discusses what you're asking for, creating a nested model. I'll do a separate answer to help you now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UserForm < Reform::Form
  property :email

  property :pet, populate_if_empty: Pet do
    property :name
  end
end
```

You then instantiate the form as follows.

```
UserForm.new(User.new)
```

And validation works vice-versa.

```
UserForm.new(User.new).validate(params[:user])
```

I recommend you buying the book. This is no covert advertise but I was basically repeating myself here hahaha.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot for coming and responding. I actually ended up buying your book a few days ago and i really like how informal/fun it is. Looking forward to the future chapters.

Comment: Just curious... could `property :name` also take a method as it's value? That way u could construct something like "Fido, a dog" for the dog's name. (for some ridiculous reason)

Comment: Thanks! You can override the reader in the form to achieve that: https://github.com/apotonick/reform#default-values-for-presentation